# How to use TryScan in F# properly

Tags: concurrency, f#, message, mailboxprocessor

I was trying to find an example about how to use `TryScan`, but haven't found any, could you help me?

What I would like to do (quite simplified example): I have a `MailboxProcessor` that accepts 
 two types of mesages.

- First one `GetState` returns current state. 
  `GetState` messages are sent quite frequently
- The other `UpdateState` is very expensive (time consuming) - e.g. downloading something from internet and then updates the state accordingly.
  `UpdateState` is called only rarely.

My problem is - messages `GetState` are blocked and wait until preceding `UpdateState` are served. That's why I tried to use `TryScan` to process all `GetState` messages, but with no luck.

My example code:

```
type Msg = GetState  of AsyncReplyChannel<int> | UpdateState
let mbox = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbox ->
             let rec loop state = async {
                // this TryScan doesn't work as expected
                // it should process GetState messages and then continue
                mbox.TryScan(fun m ->
                    match m with 
                    | GetState(chnl) -> 
                        printfn "G processing TryScan"
                        chnl.Reply(state)
                        Some(async { return! loop state})
                    | _ -> None
                ) |> ignore

                let! msg = mbox.Receive()
                match msg with
                | UpdateState ->
                    printfn "U processing"
                    // something very time consuming here...
                    async { do! Async.Sleep(1000) } |> Async.RunSynchronously
                    return! loop (state+1)
                | GetState(chnl) ->
                    printfn "G processing"
                    chnl.Reply(state)
                    return! loop state
             }
             loop 0
)

[async { for i in 1..10 do 
          printfn " U"
          mbox.Post(UpdateState)
          async { do! Async.Sleep(200) } |> Async.RunSynchronously
};
async { // wait some time so that several `UpdateState` messages are fired
        async { do! Async.Sleep(500) } |> Async.RunSynchronously
        for i in 1..20 do 
          printfn "G"
          printfn "%d" (mbox.PostAndReply(GetState))
}] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

If you try to run the code, you will see, that `GetState` message is not almost processed, because it waits for the result. On the other hand `UpdateState` is only fire-and-forget, thus blocking effectively getting state.

**Edit**

Current solution that works for me is this one:

```
type Msg = GetState  of AsyncReplyChannel<int> | UpdateState
let mbox = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbox ->
             let rec loop state = async {
                // this TryScan doesn't work as expected
                // it should process GetState messages and then continue
                let! res = mbox.TryScan((function
                    | GetState(chnl) -> Some(async {
                            chnl.Reply(state)
                            return state
                        })
                    | _ -> None
                ), 5)

                match res with
                | None ->
                    let! msg = mbox.Receive()
                    match msg with
                        | UpdateState ->
                            async { do! Async.Sleep(1000) } |> Async.RunSynchronously
                            return! loop (state+1)
                        | _ -> return! loop state
                | Some n -> return! loop n
             }
             loop 0
)
```

---

Reactions to comments: the idea with other `MailboxProcessor` or `ThreadPool` that executes `UpdateState` in parallel is great, but I don't need it currently.
All I wanted to do is to process all `GetState` messages and after that the others. I don't care that during processing `UpdateState` the agent is blocked.

I'll show you what was the problem on the output:

```
// GetState messages are delayed 500 ms - see do! Async.Sleep(500)
// each UpdateState is sent after 200ms
// each GetState is sent immediatelly! (not real example, but illustrates the problem)
 U            200ms   <-- issue UpdateState
U processing          <-- process UpdateState, it takes 1sec, so other 
 U            200ms       5 requests are sent; sent means, that it is
 U            200ms       fire-and-forget message - it doesn't wait for any result
                          and therefore it can send every 200ms one UpdateState message
G                     <-- first GetState sent, but waiting for reply - so all 
                          previous UpdateState messages have to be processed! = 3 seconds
                          and AFTER all the UpdateState messages are processed, result
                          is returned and new GetState can be sent. 
 U            200ms
 U            200ms       because each UpdateState takes 1 second
 U            200ms
U processing
 U
 U
 U
 U
U processing
G processing          <-- now first GetState is processed! so late? uh..
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
3
G
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
U processing          <-- takes 1sec
G processing          <-- after MANY seconds, second GetState is processed!
10
G
G processing
// from this line, only GetState are issued and processed, because 
// there is no UpdateState message in the queue, neither it is sent
```

Comment: The fact that you have `|> ignore` after the `TryScan` call should alert you to the fact that you're using the API wrong.  (Don't have time for a complete answer now, hope someone will beat me to it.)

Comment: I know I use it in a wrong way. But I haven't found any post about using it at all.

Comment: I think the point of `TryScan` and `Scan` is to wait for a message and timeout if it's not received.  The only difference between the two is that on timeout TryScan returns an option while Scan raises an exception.

Comment: Your edited code is still waiting on Update to finish before it replies to a GetState call.  The only way to fix this is to have Update run in another thread so the MailboxProcessor can still receive and process GetState messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the `TryScan` method will help you in this scenario. It allows you to specify timeout to be used while waiting for messages. Once some message is received, it will start processing the message (ignoring the timeout).

For example, if you wanted to wait for some specific message, but perform some other checking every second (while waiting) you could write:

```
let loop () = async {
  let! res = mbox.TryScan(function
    | ImportantMessage -> Some(async { 
          // process message 
          return 0
        })
    | _ -> None)
  match res with
  | None -> 
       // perform some check & continue waiting
       return! loop ()
  | Some n -> 
       // ImportantMessage was received and processed 
}
```

What can you do to avoid blocking the mailbox processor when processing the `UpdateState` message? The mailbox processor is (logically) single-threaded - you probably don't want to cancel the processing of `UpdateState` message, so the best option is to start processing it in background and wait until the processing completes. The code that processes `UpdateState` can then send some message back to the mailbox (e.g. `UpdateStateCompleted`).

Here is a sketch how this might look:

```
let rec loop (state) = async {
  let! msg = mbox.Receive()
  match msg with
  | GetState(repl) -> 
      repl.Reply(state)
      return! scanning state
  | UpdateState -> 
      async { 
        // complex calculation (runs in parallel)
        mbox.Post(UpdateStateCompleted newState) }
      |> Async.Start
  | UpdateStateCompleted newState ->
      // Received new state from background workflow
      return! loop newState }
```

Now that the background task is running in parallel, you need to be careful about mutable state. Also, if you send `UpdateState` messages faster than you can process them, you'll be in trouble. This can be fixed, for example, by ignoring or queueing requests when you're already processing previous one.

Comment: Thx, Tomáš. I'll still try to use `TryScan` with timeout and in case I'll in problems, there is still the possibility to use other `MailboxProcessor`.

Comment: @stej Just keep in mind that the timeout won't cancel processing of the `UpdateState` message if it already started (and that while processing the message, you cannot process any other messages in parallel).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I don't want to cancel `UpdateState`. In fact, I don't need the timeout -- all I want is to process all `GetState` messages in the queue and after that process other (currently only `UpdateState`) messages. I'll update the question a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T USE TRYSCAN!!!**

Unfortunately, the `TryScan` function in the current version of F# is broken in two ways. Firstly, the whole point is to specify a timeout but the implementation does not actually honor it. Specifically, irrelevant messages reset the timer. Secondly, as with the other `Scan` function, the message queue is examined under a lock that prevents any other threads from posting for the duration of the scan, which can be an arbitrarily long time. Consequently, the `TryScan` function itself tends to lock-up concurrent systems and can even introduce deadlocks because the caller's code is evaluated inside the lock (e.g. posting from the function argument to `Scan` or `TryScan` can deadlock the agent when the code under the lock blocks waiting to acquire the lock it is already under).

I used `TryScan` in an early prototype of my production code and it caused no end of problems. However, I managed to architect around it and the resulting architecture was actually better. In essence, I eagerly `Receive` all messages and filter using my own local queue.

Comment: Pretty interesting. However, to be honest, I expected that the queue will be locked during looking for the target message. Anyway, goot to know that it is true and that the timeout might work in a weird way. In case you could show some code that uses the local queue (you mention in the last paragraph), it would be great.

Comment: I'd expect the implementation of mailboxes (and the TPL) to be wait-free. I'll add code to my answer...

Answer (score 2):

As Tomas mentioned MailboxProcessor is single threaded.  You will need another MailboxProcessor to run the updates on a separate thread from the state getter.

```
#nowarn "40"

type Msg = 
    | GetState of AsyncReplyChannel<int> 
    | UpdateState

let runner_UpdateState = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbox ->
    let rec loop = async {
        let! state = mbox.Receive()
        printfn "U start processing %d" !state
        // something very time consuming here...
        do! Async.Sleep 100
        printfn "U done processing %d" !state
        state := !state + 1
        do! loop
    }
    loop
)

let mbox = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbox ->
    // we need a mutiple state if another thread can change it at any time
    let state = ref 0

    let rec loop = async {
        let! msg = mbox.Receive()

        match msg with
        | UpdateState -> runner_UpdateState.Post state
        | GetState chnl -> chnl.Reply !state

        return! loop 
    }
    loop)

[
    async { 
        for i in 1..10 do 
            mbox.Post UpdateState
            do! Async.Sleep 200
    };
    async { 
        // wait some time so that several `UpdateState` messages are fired
        do! Async.Sleep 1000

        for i in 1..20 do 
            printfn "G %d" (mbox.PostAndReply GetState)
            do! Async.Sleep 50
    }
] 
|> Async.Parallel 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> ignore

System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

output:

```
U start processing 0
U done processing 0
U start processing 1
U done processing 1
U start processing 2
U done processing 2
U start processing 3
U done processing 3
U start processing 4
U done processing 4
G 5
U start processing 5
G 5
U done processing 5
G 5
G 6
U start processing 6
G 6
G 6
U done processing 6
G 7
U start processing 7
G 7
G 7
U done processing 7
G 8
G U start processing 8
8
G 8
U done processing 8
G 9
G 9
U start processing 9
G 9
U done processing 9
G 9
G 10
G 10
G 10
G 10
```

You could also use ThreadPool.

```
open System.Threading

type Msg = 
    | GetState of AsyncReplyChannel<int> 
    | SetState of int
    | UpdateState

let mbox = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbox ->
    let rec loop state = async {
        let! msg = mbox.Receive()

        match msg with
        | UpdateState -> 
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((fun obj -> 
                let state = obj :?> int

                printfn "U start processing %d" state
                Async.Sleep 100 |> Async.RunSynchronously
                printfn "U done processing %d" state
                mbox.Post(SetState(state + 1))

                ), state)
            |> ignore
        | GetState chnl -> 
            chnl.Reply state
        | SetState newState ->
            return! loop newState
        return! loop state
    }
    loop 0)

[
    async { 
        for i in 1..10 do 
            mbox.Post UpdateState
            do! Async.Sleep 200
    };
    async { 
        // wait some time so that several `UpdateState` messages are fired
        do! Async.Sleep 1000

        for i in 1..20 do 
            printfn "G %d" (mbox.PostAndReply GetState)
            do! Async.Sleep 50
    }
] 
|> Async.Parallel 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> ignore
```

System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

Comment: Is the operator `!` in (`state := !state + 1 `) atomic? I use `MailboxProcessor` to avoid mutable variables and in this case I guess I could be in troubles.  The thread pool sounds good, thx.

Comment: It's not atomic.  Use the extra SetState and ThreadPool if you want immutable state.